# Trac & Apache Server: SSL & Virtual Hosts not working

Tags: apache, ssl, https, virtualhost, trac

I have configured an Ubuntu 16.04 Server with Apache and installed Trac 1.2.2 on it. I would like to access the Trac installation using SSL via https://subdomain.example.com

I have the following two .conf-files in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ right now:

**ssl.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache.key
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
```

**testinstallation.conf:**

```
WSGIScriptAlias /trac/testinstallation /var/www/html/trac/testinstallation/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi

<Location /trac/testinstallation>
  AuthType Digest
  AuthName "testinstallation"
  AuthUserFile /var/lib/trac/testinstallation/.htdigest
  Require valid-user    
</Location>
```

When I open https://subdomain.example.com/trac/testinstallation, everything works as it should - but I would like to access my Trac-environment via https://subdomain.example.com. When I change the DocumentRoot in ssl.conf to /var/www/html/trac/testinstallation, I only get to see two folders, but not the Trac-environment (I don't know how to implement the WSGIScriptAlias to the ssl.conf). Can anybody help me with this problem?

Another question: Can I run multiple installations of Trac on one server using SSL? If yes, I would probably need another VirtualHost-file - but what should be in there?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of [`WSGIScriptAlias`](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIScriptAlias.html) is the URL-path. So to access your Trac installation over just the subdomain, you can modify the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive to

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/trac/testinstallation/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
```

There is no need of mentioning the `DocumentRoot`. The `WSGIScriptAlias` directive takes care of it. If you want to run multiple Trac installations over multiple subdomains, repeat the same process that you have followed. i.e.,

- Deploy project directory
- Create Trac users
- Create vhost and enable site

Else you can run multiple Trac installation as multiple subdirectories under the same subdomain by defining multiple `WSGIScriptAlias` directives in the same vhost file.

Example of vhost file for multiple Trac installations (test1 and test2) over single subdomain:

**trac.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache.key
</VirtualHost>

WSGIScriptAlias /test1 /var/www/html/trac/test1/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
<Location /login>
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "test1"
    AuthUserFile /var/lib/trac/test1/.htdigest
    Require valid-user
</Location>

WSGIScriptAlias /test2 /var/www/html/trac/test2/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
<Location /login>
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "test2"
    AuthUserFile /var/lib/trac/test2/.htdigest
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```